# RMAN duplicate Target

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, rman

I would like to know if RMAN DUPLICATE DATABASE command restore a database on another host to the most recent time of source?

Or while Duplicating it freezes source database datafile headers and then start duplicating and if I would be missing few of the transactions/DML taking place on source database ??

Answer (score 0):

If no optional parameters are used, it would restore all the data that is archived by the RMAN archivelogger. So, not only the data which is INSIDE a redo that is archived on disk, but in addition a redo that is backed up by the RMAN backup command itself.

Consider 3 stage : active redo, archived redo (on disk), backed-up (archived) redo (on disk or tape or whatever channel)